# Kraus Operators from Lindblad equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

One should be able to formulate the time evolution given by Lindblad equation in terms of Kraus Operators. But how does one do that in practise i.e given $H$ and Lindblad operators $L_\mu$, how does one go about constructing the corresponding Kraus Operators $M_\mu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This derivation closely follows [this reference](http://www.fmt.if.usp.br/%7Egtlandi/lecture-notes-2.pdf), in the "Proof of Lindblad's theorem" section. More specifically this is the reverse of what is done there.

Start by writing your Lindblad equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm d \rho}{\mathrm d t} = -i[H,\rho] + \sum_\mu L_\mu \rho L_\mu^\dagger - \frac{1}{2} \{L_\mu^\dagger L_\mu,\rho\}
$$
Discretize it with a time step $\Delta t$, with $\frac{\mathrm d \rho}{\mathrm d t}\approx \frac{\rho(t+\Delta t) - \rho(t)}{\Delta t}$, which in the limit of $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ reduces back to your Lindblad equation. We then get:
$$
\rho(t+\Delta t) = (I +G\Delta t ) \rho (I + G^\dagger\Delta t) + \Delta t \sum_\mu L_\mu \rho L_\mu^\dagger,
$$
where $G = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_\mu L_\mu^\dagger L_\mu$.

Define now $M_u(\Delta t) = I + G\Delta t$ and $M_\mu(\Delta t) = \sqrt{\Delta t} L_\mu$ and we get the propagation of the density matrix with Kraus operators:
$$
\rho(t+\Delta t) = M_u(\Delta t) \rho M_u^\dagger(\Delta t) + \sum_\mu M_\mu(\Delta t) \rho M_\mu^\dagger(\Delta t)
$$