# Confusion regarding the derivation of Lindblad master equation

Tags: quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

I am reading theory of the master equation from [Preskill's notes](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf), section $3.5.2$. In the derivation, he writes

> In the case of an open quantum system, Markovian evolution for the
> infinitesimal time interval $dt$ may be expressed as
> \begin{equation}
> \rho(t+dt)=\mathcal{E}_{dt}\left(\rho\left(t\right)\right), \tag{3.125}
> \end{equation}
> where $\mathcal{E}_{dt}$ is a quantum channel.

......

> The channel has an operator-sum representation
> \begin{equation}
> \rho(t+dt)=\mathcal{E}_{dt}\left(\rho\left(t\right)\right)=\sum_{a} M_a \rho(t) M_a^\dagger=\rho(t)+O(dt), \tag{3.129}
> \end{equation}
> where, if we retain only terms up to linear order in $dt$, we may assume
> without loss of generality that $M_0 = I +  O(dt) $, and that $M_a$ is of
> order $\sqrt{dt}$ for $a > 0$. Each of the Kraus operators $M_{1,2,...}$ describes a
> possible "quantum jump" that the system might undergo, which occurs
> during time interval $dt$ with probability $O(dt)$, and $M_0$ describes how the
> system evolves when no jump occurs. We may write
> \begin{equation}
> M_0=I+\left(-iH+K\right)dt,
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> M_a=\sqrt{dt}L_a, \tag{3.130}
> \end{equation}

However, I did not understand how the particular forms of $M_0$ and $M_a$s were obtained. Are these chosen randomly or there is a reasoning behind choosing these particular expressions? Can anyone please help regarding these?

Comment: see this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489134/kraus-operators-from-lindblad-equation/739287#739287

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kraus Operators from Lindblad equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489134/kraus-operators-from-lindblad-equation)